# Tabs Navigation (add class to the open item menu)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create tabs navigation approaching the minimalist way possible.
So here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="tabs">
   <ul>
      <li>Tab A</li>

      <li>Tab B</li>

      <li>Tab C</li>
   </ul>

   <div>
      <div>
         <h4>Tab A</h4>
      </div>

      <div>
         <h4>Tab B</h4>
      </div>

      <div>
         <h4>Tab C</h4>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*Tabs Navigation*/
.tabs ul {
   margin: 0;
}

    .tabs ul li {
        color: #fff;
       background-color: #6B6B6B;
       border: 1px solid #6B6B6B;

       padding: 5px 10px;
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
        cursor: pointer;      
    }

.tabs > div {
    border: 1px solid #6B6B6B;
    padding: 20px;

    width: 100%;  
    display: inline-block;
}

.tabs div > div:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;   
}
```

JS:

```
//Tabs Navigation
$('.tabs ul li').click(function() {
   $('.tabs div > div:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').show().siblings().hide();
});
```

And here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5JqpL/).

**My Question:**
I am trying to add class .active to the menu item related to section opened, but I can't figure our how! what logic or approach to go for... Can anyone please direct me to the right place?

Comment: You have not added jquery library. see this http://jsfiddle.net/5JqpL/1/

Comment: hahah, thanks! I have it added in my actual site, but still don't know how to add the classes to current open items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine add jquery library from left side select box

```
$('.tabs ul li').click(function () {
$('ul li').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
$('.tabs div > div:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').show().siblings().hide();
});
```

Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5JqpL/3/)

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to add classes to the current open menu items tho

Comment: Thanks, this works - one thing tho - how can I default the first menu with the class? so it has the class but default. Also can I just hide and show the divs using JS? as now I am doing it using CSS...

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you think it is reliable to use?

Comment: @Leo ya our requirement is satisfied by this `:-)`

Comment: @Leo http://jsfiddle.net/5JqpL/7/ see this one it has some animation when opening

Answer (score 1):

First of all Add the jquery library. and to `addClass` to current and `removeClass` from siblings try this:

```
 //Tabs Navigation
$('.tabs ul li').click(function (index) {
$('.tabs div > div:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').show().addClass('active ').siblings().removeClass('active ').hide();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5JqpL/4/)**